# What are the new and old treasures relative to the kingdom of heaven in Matthew 13:52?

Tags: matthew, christology, parables

Matthew 13:52 NIV

52 He said to them, “Therefore every teacher of the law who has become a disciple in the kingdom of heaven is like the owner of a house who brings out of his storeroom ***new treasures as well as old***.”

What are the old and new treasures in the parable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew 13:52

> He said to them, “Therefore every **teacher** of the law who has become a disciple in the kingdom of heaven is like the owner of a house who brings out of his storeroom new treasures as well as old.”

Who were these teachers?

Matthew 23:34

> Therefore I am sending you prophets and sages and **teachers**. Some of them you will kill and crucify; others you will flog in your synagogues and pursue from town to town.

Jesus referred to the teachers/preachers. These teachers were well-versed with the OT. Afte becoming Jesus' disciples, they learned the new gospel truths. Jesus stressed the importance of teaching both nuggets/treasures from the OT and the NT. We can apply this to biblical typology.

Peter practiced this in Acts 2:

> 22“Fellow Israelites, listen to this: **Jesus** of Nazareth was a man accredited by God to you by miracles, wonders and signs, which God did among you through him, as you yourselves know. 23This man was handed over to you by God’s deliberate plan and foreknowledge; and you, with the help of wicked men, put him to **death** by nailing him to the **cross**. 24But God **raised** him from the dead, freeing him from the agony of death, because it was impossible for death to keep its hold on him. 25 **David** said about him:
>
> “ ‘I saw the Lord always before me.
> Because he is at my right hand,
> I will not be shaken.
> 26Therefore my heart is glad and my tongue rejoices;
> my body also will rest in hope,
> 27because you will not abandon me to the realm of the dead,
> you will not let your **holy one see decay**.

Peter cited David's Psalm 16:10 and applied it to Jesus' resurrection.

Answer (score 2):

**What are the new and old treasures relative to the kingdom of heaven in Matthew 13:52?**

The Greek word gram·ma·teusʹ is rendered “scribe” when referring to a group of Jewish teachers who were versed in the Law, but here the expression is used with regard to Jesus’ disciples who were trained to teach others. The answer will be based on the translations below.

Contemporary English Version Matthew 13:52

> So he told them, "Every student of the Scriptures who becomes a
> disciple in the kingdom of heaven is like someone who brings out new
> and old treasures from the storeroom."

Holman Christian Standard BibleNMatthew 13:52

> "Therefore," He said to them, "every student of Scripture instructed
> in the kingdom of heaven is like a landowner who brings out of his
> storeroom what is new and what is old."

From the moment we start reading the Bible, we have the opportunity to collect spiritual treasures from God's Word. As we continue to read, we develop what Jesus described as the "treasure" of old and new truths. God will help us to collect more treasures into our treasure store if we search for them as for a hidden treasure.

Proverbs 2:4-7 NASB

> 4 If you seek her as silver  And search for her as for hidden
> treasures; 5 Then you will understand the fear of the Lord, And
> discover the knowledge of God. 6 For the Lord gives wisdom;  From His
> mouth come knowledge and understanding. 7 He stores up sound wisdom
> for the upright; He is a shield to those who walk in integrity,